# How to have View output is same as node output

Tags: views

I have a content type called poem and a View page that has path like poem/% too. There is a View page for listing the poems called /poems. The poems page will list all the poem titles linked the actual poem 
   (eg: "a href="poem/1">What a world ).

I have a block in the poem view to show all the poems written by the poet. 
My problem here is when I go to the node by /node/1, I can see the block that list all the poems written by the poet who wrote the node/1 but when I go like /poem/1 I am not seeing the block that list the poems. The node/1 view has bold header of the title but that's missing in my /poem/1 too.

Please help me how to make poem/1 to have the same view as the /node/1.

/poems -> this will list all the poem titles in site, title link would be 
/poem/1 instead of node/1

/poem/1 -> display poem content + it should display all the titles of the poem written by the author (/poem/1)

poem list view
[image]

poem view[image]

node view of the same poem
[image]

poem view setup
[image]

Comment: It seems to be clear but not for me. :) It's confusing..poem, poem view, poem block. It seems there is something missing in views block. If possible try to make it simple or elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I go like /poem/1 I am not seeing the block that list the poems. The node/1 view has bold header of the title but that's missing in my /poem/1 too.

In the Blocks Admin UI at `admin/structure/blocks` be sure the Block for your `block view` for a *poem listing* is enabled for the `url path = poem/*`.

You can also assign blocks to regions easily with the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working yet. There is no restriction on the block view. I am going to attach some screenshots.

Comment: What I said is not a configuration value in the Views UI. It is in the Blocks UI in `admin/structure/blocks`

Comment: It's enabled and the region is secondary. I am not sure how to enable for the speicfic path. I don't have any restrictions in block visibility settings. Please let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: The contextual filter setup was wrong - I set to raw and it's working fine now. Thanks for your time.